# Smartthings Hub Keeps Losing track of Deadbolt Status

Tags: samsung-smartthings, zwave

I have a Schlage Z-Wave deadbolt paired to my v2 Smartthings hub. Recently the lock has been blowing through batteries and it will often show the lock as unavailable even though the lock touchpad works. I also have noticed that the hub is pinging the lock very frequently as well. The first set of batteries lasted about 9 months but now I get about 2-3 months per set.

What could be causing the increased battery use and instability and how can I fix the issue?

Comment: Given that it costs $299, have you tried contacting Schlage?

Comment: Firmware update, log file to see if there is any suspicious activity...

Comment: Have not called Schlage. I don't at this time believe it is an issue with the lock.  I will get the log file from the hub and see if there is anything of note.